# Surface integral of constant vector $c$ times the unit normal vector $n$ is identically zero.

Tags: calculus, vector-fields, surface-integrals

Let $S$ be closed, oriented surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with unit normal vector ${\bf n}$. Let ${\bf c}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a ${\it constant}$ vector field. Show that the surface integral
$$\iint_S{\bf c\cdot n} dS$$
is identically zero.

Because in the comment, Ivo Terek hinted on the curl of the constant vector field.
Here is my updated thought:
$$\iint_S{\bf c\cdot n} dS=\oint_{Curve} curl(c)\cdot n dt=\oint_{Curve} 0\cdot n dt$$
Since the curve starts and ends at the same point, say $a$
by integration property,
$$\oint_{a}^a curl(c)\cdot n =0$$

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit the question to add more context and show your thoughts on the question / your attempt.

Comment: Suggest to read about divergence theorem, many online resources are available.

Comment: What is the curl of a constant field?